# Flask and SQLAlchemy - how can I get the connection string from a config file?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm creating a flask project and struggling with the setup.

I want to use SQLAlchemy for database access. The process is described here:
https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/

As you can see, in this example the connection string is hard coded (and this is the case in most examples of setting up SQLAlchemy I found).
In a real life app, of course, I want to have `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` in a `config.py` (or in my case, in a `.env` file, but that's beside the point).

The problem then occurs that in my `application\__init__.py` the db_session needs to be imported, and inside db_session the connection string is needed. At that point in time, the app isn't available yet, so app.config isn't useable:

```
from application.database import db_session
from application.main import main_bp


def init_app():

    """Initialize the core application."""
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object('config.Config')

    @app.teardown_appcontext
    def shutdown_session(exception=None):
        db_session.remove()

    with app.app_context():

        # Register Blueprints
        app.register_blueprint(main_bp)
```

But at the moment db_session is imported, the app context, and `app.config` isn't available yet. My solution now is to put the database connection string in an env variable first (see below). But that's a bit of a hacky workaround. I'd much rather have it in the app.config.

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, declarative_base

connection_string = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI')  

engine = create_engine(connection_string, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False})
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()


def init_db():
    import models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

Does anyone know, or have an example of how this is usually managed?

Comment: Usually, you should use a different file/module to handle DB and import that in your app. And as you have to manage the database instance in several places in your app it's always better to use class based approach but you are not forced to. If you just want to pass the session where needed you can do that. But for that, you have to put the session in a separate file. 
You can find the file based approach here - https://github.com/Ananto30/cap-em
And class based approach here - https://bitbucket.org/ananto30/youtube-tracker/src/master/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following if you have .env file

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = environ.get('DATABASE_URL')
```

Or the following for config file

```
app.config.from_pyfile('config.cfg')
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, that's not the problem. The problem is at the moment db_session is imported, the app context, and app.config isn't available yet.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm not familiar with using this "@app.teardown_appcontext
    def shutdown_session(exception=None):
        db_session.remove()"

It seems I misunderstood the problem. My bad Erik. I hope you end up finding a solution!